# How to render child components in parent component in vue.js and only render the changes occurred in child component?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, parent-child

What I have done so far is created two componenets which are present in `src/components` folder and I want to add these components which is contained by parent component present in `src/views` folder.

I have one component named form.vue and another component `background.vue`

And what I want is, to show the `form.vue` (which contains a form) on top of `backgound.vue` (which is for background purpose). So every time, any changes happen in child,forces the whole parent page to re-render. So is there any way to solve this ?

Below are folder structure:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**create 3 components and call 2 of them into 3rd component.**

For example:

```
You have
component1.vue
component2.vue
component3.vue
```

In component3.vue:

```
<script>
    //import components
    import componentOne from '/path/to/component1'
    import componentTwo from '/path/to/component2'
    //now register them locally to use them in this component
    export default{
        components:{componentOne, componentTwo}

    }
   //now call these components in <template> section using kebab case
   <template>
     <div>
          <component-one />  //camelCAse name of component in <script> tag  is used in kebab case in template section
          <component-two />  // means componentTwo will called as <component-two/>
     </div>     
   </template>

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html) for that, so in your background.vue you would have:

```
<template>
 ...
   <slot><slot> <!-- place where the external component will be rendered -->
 ...
 </template>
```

and then in the main component, you would have:

```
<background>
  <my-form></my-form>
</background>
```

Comment: Hi Florentin, Thanks for your response, but i didn't understand the below 3 lines

Comment: @Dcoder Hi, you mean `<background> <my-form></my-form></background>` ? 

This is what you would put in a page component (page1.vue) in which you would want to use the background and the form.